# A graph that all its vertices are vertices cut

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

Is there any graph that all its vertices are cut vertices?
I couldn't find a graph with this property? and if there is no such graph  how can i prove that it does not exist.

Comment: The earlier question is about connected graphs, but it’s clear that if very connected graph has a non-cut vertex, then every graph has a non-cut vertex.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such (finite) graph.

Suppose such a graph $G$ existed.  We may assume WLOG it is connected.  For each vertex  $v$, let $f(v)$ be the minimum number of vertices in the connected components of the graph $G - v$ obtained by deleting $v$.  Take $v$ that minimizes $f$, and let $C$ be a connected component of $G - v$ with
$f(v)$ vertices.  At least one vertex $w$ of $C$ is adjacent to $v$.  Now in $G - w$, one connected component must contain $v$, and this will also contain all other vertices not in $C$.  Any other connected component of $G - w$ will therefore be a proper subset of $C$, so $f(w) < f(v)$, contradiction.