# Graph Theory: Proving that a block-cutpoint graph has no cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Obviously, such a graph doesn't exist because it would be a block of its own and it can be further reduced to an actual block-cutpoint graph of consisting of a single vertex.
The actual problem is how to prove this by contradiction, specifically by assuming that a block-cutpoint graph that contains a cycle might exist.

EDIT: Few definitions for the key-terms, copy-pasted from [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245642/maximum-number-of-vertices-of-a-block-cutpoint-graph)!.

> The block-cutpoint graph of a graph $G$ is the bipartite graph which consists of the set of cut-vertices of $G$ and a set of vertices which represent the blocks of $G$.
>
> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph.
>   Let $v$ be a vertex of $G$. Then $v$ is a cut-vertex of $G$ iff the vertex deletion $G−v$ is a vertex cut of $G$.That is, such that $G−v$ is disconnected.
>
> A block is a maximal biconnected subgraph of a given graph $G$.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the definition you are using for a *block-cutpoint* graph.

Comment: Is the graph consisting of a three-cycle where each vertex is adjacent to a singleton vertex a *block-cutpoint* graph? The graph with edges $\{1,2\}\;\{2,3\}\;\{1,3\}\;\{1,4\}\;\{2,5\}\;\{3,6\}\;$.

Comment: @MikePierce Weirdly this is the second cutpoint graph question today. A block-cutpoint graph is a bipartite graph which has a vertex for every block in the original graph and a vertex for every cutpoint. There is an edge between a block-vertex and a cutpoint-vertex if the cutpoint is contained in the block.

Comment: @MikePierce What gilleain said. Nevertheless, I edited my question by including definitions for the key terms related to my problem.

Comment: I found an answer in the meantime: [link](https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/logik/lehre/WS11-12/Para/Ex3_Solsb.pdf). Still, any better suggestion for a solution would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine our block-cut point graph has a cycle like {($v_1$,$b_1$),($b_1$, $v_2$),...,($b_n$,$v_1$)} (for each i, $v_i$ is a member of the set of cut vertices and $b_i$ is a member of the set of vertices which represent the blocks of $G$.)

Now you can easily see $v_1$ cannot be a cut vertex in our original graph $G$. A contradiction!